# How to stop writing to a bag file when using the rosbag2_py API?

Tags: python, ros2, ros-galactic, rosbag2

I'd like to modify [this example of recording a bag file from a ROS node written in Python](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Advanced/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-Py.html) to be able to effectively start and stop recording using a service call. My thought is I could create `self.writer = rosbag2_py.SequentialWriter()` in my service callback, and add some logic in the callbacks for the topic subscriptions to ensure that it will only try to write the data if `self.writer` exists and is ready to be written to.

I think what I describe should work for *starting* recording, my question is how will I handle safely *stopping* the recording, such that I can subsequently start recording a new bag file again with a subsequent service call. Since there is an `open` function on `SequentialWriter`, I was expecting to see a `close` or `flush` function, but I don't see such functionality in [the exposed Python API](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/rolling/rosbag2_py/src/rosbag2_py/_writer.cpp#L92-L104). My guess then is that maybe this isn't working like how I normally think of files being "open" in Python.

So, what I would like to know: what is the correct way to "stop" recording when using the Python API? Is it sufficient to simply call `self.writer.open()` with different `StorageOptions` that assign a new `uri` to save to? If I do that, am I somehow leaving "open" resources dangling?

**UPDATE (1/2):**
It seems there is in fact a `close` function on `SequentialWriter`, but only in [the C++ API](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/rolling/rosbag2_cpp/src/rosbag2_cpp/writers/sequential_writer.cpp#L152-L170) and it's not offered yet in the Python bindings. There is [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/issues/876) that gives some awareness to this.

**UPDATE (2/2):**
I wrote what I described in C++, and me calling the `close` function on `SequentialWriter` just caused my program to crash without any error. I ended up finding the package [system_data_recorder](https://github.com/osrf/system_data_recorder) that implements the functionality I needed of being able to programmatically start/stop bag recording. They use node lifecycles to manage start/pause/resume/stop recording and have the added benefit that they can copy incremental chunks of the bags to a copy location so that you can incrementally save your data to a backup. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach (that was often done in ROS1 since there wasn't a stable rosbag API) would be to instead use Python subprocess to call the `ros2 bag record` command as you would from the command line - it is then very easy to send a ctrl-C to the subprocess.

Comment: I do recall doing this sort of thing in ROS1, following guidance similar to what's suggested here: https://answers.ros.org/question/10714/start-and-stop-rosbag-within-a-python-script/. However, I recall that causing me many headaches because there were many child processes that got spawned by rosbag, and killing it cleanly without creating orphans was a challenge. The system_data_recorder I think has the best approach, leveraging the lifecycle node capabilities in ROS2.